# How to make css background-blend-mode work with gradients?

Tags: css, gradient

I have a page with multiple backgrounds: one with gradient and one with texture pattern. But background-blend-mode doesn't work. Chrome appears to show only gradient layer. When I try to blend two background-images or background-image with solid background-color it works well. But not with gradient. Is something wrong?

```
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url('../images/noisy.png');
background-color: rgba(29, 84, 140, 1);
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(36,138,166,1) 0%,rgba(21,112,145,1) 42%,rgba(5,58,103,1) 100%);
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(36,138,166,1) 0%,rgba(21,112,145,1) 42%,rgba(5,58,103,1) 100%);  
background-blend-mode: multiply;}
```

And my goal is something like that:
[image: pic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does work with gradients you just need to use multiple backgrounds.

The problem with your current code is that you are only setting one background.

First you set `background` to an image:

`background: url('../images/noisy.png');`

Then you *override* the image and set `background` to a gradient:

`background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(36,138,166,1) 0%,rgba(21,112,145,1) 42%,rgba(5,58,103,1) 100%);`

To assign multiple backgrounds you need to comma seperate them:

`background: background1, background2, ...,  backgroundN;`

Using your gradient:

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEnJm.png');
    background-color: rgba(29, 84, 140, 1);
    /* ^ fallbacks for crappy IE ^ */

    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEnJm.png'), -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,     rgba(36,138,166,1) 0%,rgba(21,112,145,1) 42%,rgba(5,58,103,1) 100%);
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEnJm.png'), radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(36,138,166,1) 0%,rgba(21,112,145,1) 42%,rgba(5,58,103,1) 100%);  
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

A gradient similar to your image example:

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEnJm.png'), -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(21,112,145,1) 0%, rgba(36,138,166,1) 100%);
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEnJm.png'), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(21,112,145,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(36,138,166,1)));
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEnJm.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(21,112,145,1) 0%,rgba(36,138,166,1) 100%);
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEnJm.png'), -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(21,112,145,1) 0%,rgba(36,138,166,1) 100%);
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEnJm.png'), -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(21,112,145,1) 0%,rgba(36,138,166,1) 100%);
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEnJm.png'), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(21,112,145,1) 0%,rgba(36,138,166,1) 100%);
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```