# CSS / HTML gradient fill pattern is glitchy in Firefox

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

The following is a minimal (ish) example in which a chequered gradient fill pattern is glitchy in Firefox (version 74) i.e. it is not pixel perfect. There are line artefacts. Why is this? Is that normal? Is there a fix, other than using an image for the background?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <style>
        .r{width:20px;height:20px;background:white;float:left;}
        .w{overflow:hidden;}
        #p75{
            width:80px;
            height:20px;
            background-position:0px 0px,10px 10px;
            background-size:20px 20px;
            background-image:linear-gradient(45deg,#ccc 25%,transparent 25%,transparent 75%,#ccc 75%,#ccc 100%),
                linear-gradient(45deg,#ccc 25%,white 25%,white 75%,#ccc 75%,#ccc 100%);
            float:left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="w">
        <div class="r">0</div>
        <div id="p75"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55455760/8620333 .. in the near future you can rely on coninc-gradient but actually I suggest the SVG method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotating gradients have always had that problem for more on that check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091401/background-image-linear-gradient-jagged-edged-result-needs-to-be-smooth-edged)

One way to fix the issue is to not use angles at all, and make use of repeating gradients.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: 
  repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #fff 0px 10px, transparent 10px 20px), 
  repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #000 0px 10px, #fff 10px 20px);
  background-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

**Edit: thanks to @Temani Afif** without repeating gradient.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(90deg, #fff 50%, transparent 0) 0 0/20px 100%, 
    linear-gradient(0deg,  #000 50%, #fff        0) 0 0/100% 20px;
  background-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

Comment: blend mode work fine with only gradients: https://jsfiddle.net/wbg691z2/

Comment: also you don't need to define the size since it's a repeating gradient: https://jsfiddle.net/wbg691z2/1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Weird i tried many times i even looked it up and found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26913450/7148391)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Right i have never worked with repeating gradients before lol, thanks for the heads up, much appreciated =)

Comment: you will need size if you do the same with non repeating gradient: https://jsfiddle.net/wbg691z2/2/ ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't know how i missed that, i've tested it without the repeating gradients and it didn't work, i will update the answer, Thanks :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif the `0` color stop means the beginning of the current color which would be the end the of the previous color, Right ?

Comment: more precisely : *If a color stop has a position that is less than the specified position of any color stop before it in the list, set its position to be equal to the largest specified position of any color stop before it.*. The browser will transform it to 50%. This is a trick to make color stop easy to manipulate. You only change one and the other will follow to avoid changing all of them. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54071464/8620333

Answer (score 1):

you can overlap them a tiny bit , here i added 0.1% to the color start/stop setup , chrome use to be the one.

```css
  .r {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  float: left;
}

.w {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#p75,
.p75 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  background-position: 0px 0px, 10px 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ccc 25%, transparent 25.1%, transparent 75%, #ccc 75.1%, #ccc 100%), linear-gradient(45deg, #ccc 25%, white 25.1%, white 75%, #ccc 75.1%, #ccc 100%);
  float: left;
}

.p75 {
margin:0 1em 1em;
  height: 200px;
  width:100%;

  background-size: 19px 19px;
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <div class="r">0</div>
  <div id="p75"></div>
</div>
<p>or decrease background-size of 1px</p>

<div class="p75"></div>
```

Another solution is to set the whole pattern from triangles and pretune values via css custom properties :

```css
div {
  --bgsize: 40;
  --sq1: 0 0;
  --sq2: calc(var(--bgsize) / 2 * 1px)  calc(var(--bgsize) / 2 * 1px);
  --sq3: var(--sq2);
  --sq4: calc(var(--bgsize) * 1px ) 0px;
}

#a20:checked ~ div { --bgsize: 20; }
#a50:checked ~ div { --bgsize: 50; }
#a150:checked~ div { --bgsize: 150;}
#a100:checked~ div { --bgsize: 100;}
div { 

  height:200px;  
  background:
  linear-gradient(45deg,  gray 25% , transparent 26%),
  linear-gradient(225deg, gray 25% , transparent 26%),
  linear-gradient(45deg,  gray 25% , transparent 26%),
  linear-gradient(225deg, gray 25% , transparent 26%) 
  ;
  background-position: 
  var(--sq1) , 
  var(--sq2) , 
  var(--sq3) , 
  var(--sq4);
  background-size: calc(var(--bgsize) * 1px)  calc(var(--bgsize) * 1px );
}
```

```html
reset bg-size:<br>
<label for=a20>20px</label><input  type=radio  name=test  id=a20>
<label for=a100>100px</label><input type=radio  name=test  id=a100>
<label for=a150>150px</label><input  type=radio  name=test  id=a150>
<div></div>
```

demo with option to reset --bgsize and color 
 https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GRJGXwv

Comment: why not having the `--bgsize` with px unit and avoid the extra multiplication with 1px later?

Comment: @TemaniAfif because you may want to use % or else unit  in the end ;) , i should have put the unit inside a var too . take care.

Comment: ah no, it won't work with percentage because you will get trapped with the percetange behavior that is not the same as pixel one: https://jsfiddle.net/wbg691z2/3/ .. you will need a more complex (probably impossible) code

Comment: @TemaniAfif turn % into vw/vh/vmin or vmax and its fine ;) , i commented back too fast , but that was the idea ;)